# Include concatenation operator ( + ) with in the string in java

Tags: java, angularjs, encryption, aes

I am **encrypting** a text containing User Information in **java**  using **"AES"** algorithm and appending it to the url,(which will be sent to the customer to have access to the application. And i am success in retrieving the **encrypted text from the url** in the client side **(AngularJS)** and send it back to the **Server side(java)** through a **rest** call to decrypt it and retrieve the corresponding Information.

But the problem i am facing is , since the encrypted text include **"+"** ,Java is treating it as a **concatenation operator** and is replacing it with a **space** changing the original encryption format before decryption

I tried `encValue=encValue.replaceAll("\\+", "\\\\+")`  for the

**ecryptedText** (encrypted URL parameter fetched in angularJS and when the same is  passed to Java)

`a6fPPqUwnkobdB7D8B53en+FlNcEt+Ehd4Ze6srqM/Q=`

**The result in java (Same Encrypted Value)**

`a6fPPqUwnkobdB7D8B53en\\ FlNcEt Ehd4Ze6srqM/Q=`

I want the Encrypted text to retain its original structure

Thank you

Comment: As an aside, when you talk about "client side in Java" I'm 99% sure you mean "client in Javascript". After all, the "JS" of "AngularJS" is for Javascript, not Java...

Comment: Thats exactly right, but since i found out the problem in java,( after the rest call ,passing the url parameter  to java)  , i has to assume that it was java i am having problems with

Comment: Even if the problem is in Java (which it isn't) that doesn't mean the client side is in Java. Your bold text "ecryptedText (client side) in Java" is simply inaccurate and confusing.

Comment: sorry my bad , i have changed to the appropriate sentence,
 Thank U

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But the problem i am facing is , since the encrypted text include "+" ,Java i treating it as a concatenation operator

That sounds very, very unlikely to me. It wouldn't explain why you're getting a space, either. Instead, this sounds like this is a URL-encoding issue... normally `+` in a URL query parameter is used to encode space.

Basically, you should either use a URL-safe base64 encoding, or run the string through a URL-encoder before including it in the URL. So your query parameter should be

```
a6fPPqUwnkobdB7D8B53en%2BFlNcEt%2BEhd4Ze6srqM/Q=
```

Comment: Hello @Job Skeet, the encoding has been done using base64 encoder in java(java.util.Base64)..  And i have made sure that there is no space priory in the text after enrytion and encoding using base64. I am even making a check in the client side for spaces,. But the problem here is as soon as the request is received in Java, and when i print it, i encounter space replaced with each of that of  "+" characters

Comment: @Nishi: That's a binary to text encoding though. You're trying to use that text on a URL, so you need to url-encode it. Do you understand that + in a URL query parameter is the encoded form of space?

Comment: sorry , i might sound a bit dumb, but i am a naive person to this process...so do u mean that after i encrypt the text and before appending it to the url (that is shared in public) , i should do a url-encoding of that encrypted text?

Comment: @Job Skeet , i tried URL Encoding after encryption and before placing it in the url,, and it worked..
    Thank u ...

Answer (score 1):

So mainly the problem was as Jon Skeet pointed out, it was the **URL Encoding** issue, since **"+"** character in query parameter is the **Encoded form** of **Space**.

So just the **Base64 encoding after the AES encryption** `a6fPPqUwnkobdB7D8B53en+FlNcEt+Ehd4Ze6srqM/Q=` will cause problem during the process of **decrypting** the text when the same is used as a **query parameter in URL** (since it includes "+", encoded form of space in the URL query parameter).

**Solution**

Perform a **URL encoding** of the encrypted text before actually using it as a URL query parameter.

`a6fPPqUwnkobdB7D8B53en%2BFlNcEt%2BEhd4Ze6srqM%2FQ%3D`

Here eventually, not only **"+"** , but all the **URL specific** characters will the transformed to the corresponding **character-set** (the default character-set in HTML5 is UTF-8. Check [ASCII Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)).

And once you fetch that particular URL query parameter in the through JavaScript (client), the transformation to original text happens automatically (well that what I experienced).

`a6fPPqUwnkobdB7D8B53en+FlNcEt+Ehd4Ze6srqM/Q=`